# Is there any way to add statement in CASE - WHEN in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

So im trying to add "AND" in my select statement if input parameter :STATUS != null. For now i came to this

```
... WHERE NSR_DATCRE BETWEEN to_date(:NUMDAYS1, 'DD.MM.RRRR') 
AND to_date(:NUMDAYS2, 'DD.MM.RRRR')
AND 
  CASE WHEN :STATUS = null then NSR_STATUS != 1 
  else NSR_STATUS = :STATUS
AND NVL(NSR_MAGAZ,-1) ...
```

also i tryed something like this ( from this you probably will have better understating of what im triyng to archive here)

```
... WHERE NSR_DATCRE BETWEEN to_date(:NUMDAYS1, 'DD.MM.RRRR') AND to_date(:NUMDAYS2, 'DD.MM.RRRR')
AND (NSR_STATUS = :STATUS AND :STATUS != null) or (NSR_STATUS != 1 AND :STATUS = null)
AND NVL(NSR_MAGAZ,-1) ...
```

Im really stuck for now. Any suggestions?

Comment: :STATUS **IS** null or :STATUS **IS NOT** null. :STATUS = null will be always evaluated to FALSE.

Comment: Now its working only when :STATUS is not null. Second 'OR' statement not working

Comment: Unrelated, but: why are you passing DATE values as strings?

Comment: This is for oracle reports. Its easier to call it from java with string command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from Nick's comment, also use parentheses when mixing AND & OR.

OR has lower precedence than AND, and will always be processed last if you don't use parentheses.

```
... WHERE NSR_DATCRE BETWEEN to_date(:NUMDAYS1, 'DD.MM.RRRR') AND to_date(:NUMDAYS2, 'DD.MM.RRRR')
AND (
     (NSR_STATUS = :STATUS AND :STATUS is not null) 
     or (NSR_STATUS != 1 AND :STATUS is null)
    )
AND NVL(NSR_MAGAZ,-1) = ?? ...
```

Your CASE statement didn't work because CASE can't return boolean conditions (`1=1`, `NSR_STATUS != 1`, etc).

Answer (score 1):

CASE expressions should return a value, not a logical expression:

```
... WHERE NSR_DATCRE BETWEEN to_date(:NUMDAYS1, 'DD.MM.RRRR') AND
          to_date(:NUMDAYS2, 'DD.MM.RRRR') AND 
          1 = CASE
                WHEN :STATUS IS NULL AND NSR_STATUS != 1 THEN 1
                WHEN NSR_STATUS = :STATUS THEN 1
                ELSE 0
              END AND
          NVL(NSR_MAGAZ,-1) ...
```